# How the function executes line by line in c++

Tags: c++

for example the function is

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int print(void);

int main(void)

{
    cout << "The Lucky " << print() << endl;   

    return 0;
}

int print(void)

{
    cout << "No : ";

    return 3;
}
```

how will it be executed line by line,,, since I am a beginner that's why I am asking such questions

Comment: Which function are you asking about?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: _"how will it be executed line by line"_ What do you mean? Could you elaborate please.

Comment: Why don't you just check ? If you use a debugger (usually, IDE provide embbed support for them) you will be able to see the execution line by line. If you use linux, GDB, else, i don't know.

Comment: You could set up the options for your compiler to *generate an assembly language listing* and follow the assembly code.

Comment: I am asking about the user defined functions.

Comment: I am asking how to dry run a program containing function @πάνταῥεῖ

Answer (score 1):

The concept of line do not exist in C++, or in most modern language for what it matters. The evaluation and execution order of C++ is, most of the time, what you would expect. Since you're a beginner, I will not bother you with the gory details.

In your example, here is what happens:

1. `std::ostream::operator<<(std::cout, "The Lucky")` is called, which sends "The Lucky" into the standard output;
2. `print()` is called;
3. `std::ostream::operator<<(std::cout, "No : ")` is called, which sends "No : " into the standard output;
4. `print()` returns 3;
5. `std::ostream::operator<<(std::cout, 3)` is called, which sends "3" into the standard output;
6. `std::ostream::operator<<(std::cout, std::endl)` is called, which sends "\n" into the standard output and flushes it.

Finally, you got "The Lucky No : 3\n" on your terminal.

Comment: @SergeyA I've edited my answer, you were right. But I'd like to ask you why do you downvote me for such details? it's not the first time. Do I need to seek help with a moderator or are we OK you and I?

Comment: @YSC, I am going to downvote incorrect answers, no  matter who posts them. You are free to raise a complain, of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream> //<- Includes the standard in and out stream library

using namespace std; //<- imports symbols from the std namespace so you can avoid "std::" in front of standard library symbols.


int print(void); //<- prototype for the print function that will return
                 //an integer with no parameters

int main(void) //<- implementation of the main function
{
    cout << "The Lucky " << print() << endl; //<- print "The Lucky " and the
                                             //result of the print function to
                                             //the output stream/terminal
                                             //and go to a new line after

    return 0; //<- return 0 (in main indicates no errors on program end
}

int print(void) //<- implementation of prototyped 'print' function from above
{
    cout << "No : "; //<- print "No : " to the terminal/output stream

    return 3; //<- return the number 3 to the function's caller
}
```

Output should be: `The Lucky No : 3`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not enter in the thread world, everything is like a book, but you jump from page to page. By jumping to a page, i refer to a function. While you are at that page, you cannot read the main page right? Same thing. Your main will wait for it, then continue. Thats why you can put a function returning a boolean inside the condition of a `if`.

There is also many other things about pre-compilation and order of initialisation, but there is alot of details about it, so you better ask for a specific question when you will hit that kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first function to be executed in a C++ program is the `main` function - hence this will be executed first. During the line

```
cout << "The Lucky " << print() << endl;
```

The `print` function is called - so the code jumps to the `print` function and executes what is there (it outputs "No : "). Then it *returns* the value 3, and goes back to where it was.

```
cout << "The Lucky " << print()[Here now] << endl;
```

Because `print` returned a value of 3, that value is printed. Then a newline is printed (`endl`) and finally the `main` function returns, signifying the end of the program.

Comment: Thank you very much @otah0077